# Adonis and PostgreSQL: create table "adonis_schema"... fails with 'permission denied for schema public'

Tags: postgresql, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

I have been following the [dockerizing-adonis](https://docs.adonisjs.com/cookbooks/dockerizing-adonis) tutorial which uses PostgreSQL as database.

I am new to Postgres and do not completely understand its user/role/schema concepts yet.

In the tutorial pretty early on I'm instructed to create `dockerConfig/postgres-dev-init.sql` with this content:

```sql
CREATE USER adonis with encrypted password 'adonis';
CREATE DATABASE adonis_app;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE adonis_app TO adonis;
```

Then further down in the docker-compse.yml there is

```yaml
environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

I followed the tutorial and also updated the `.env` file - the tutorial works - but does not use the database.
So I created a model with a migration: `node ace make:model User -m`
now I want to run that migration to create the User table.
Running `node ace migration:run` gets me the error

> [ error ]  create table "adonis_schema" ("id" serial primary key,
> "name" varchar(255) not null, "batch" integer not null,
> "migration_time" timestamptz default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - permission
> denied for schema public

I want this setup with 2 users (`postgres` as the root user, `adonis` to be used by adonis) to work the way its suggested in the tutorial and understand postgre better (later i want to add a grafana user with just read-access).

- Why is the permission denied? Does the init `.sql` file need more instructions? Shouldn't the user adonis by default already have the required create rights on the public schema, or am I misunderstanding that concept of the public schema in postgres?
- Am I somehow completely on the wrong track, or should the tutorial somehow make this work and misses something (In which case I would create an issue for the adonis doc ...)?

Answer (score 1):

Tutorial should work. I use it myself :)

I believe you skipped this part of docs:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, and sorry for not mentioning this explicitly, but no: I did not skip it.
my .env contains the correct values `PG_USER=adonis`, `PG_PASSWORD=adonis` and the `PG_DB_NAME` (I changed that to my own name, but in all spots in the .sql and the .env as well)

Comment: I might have found my Problem: I deviated from the tutorial in the I used the `postgres:15.0-alpine` image instead of `postgres:13`.
I just found: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-15.html stating
'Remove PUBLIC creation permission on the public schema (Noah Misch)'
It might be worth adding a hint to this in the tutorial for other foolhearted devs that blindly try the latest postgres version.